# Chef Berks Install (Berkshelf) Timesout contacting Artifactory repository (Faraday Timeout / Actor Crashed)

Tags: timeout, chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk, berksfile

**Artifactory** 5.8.4 Professional

**Chef Development Kit** Version: 1.1.16

**chef-client** version: 12.17.44

**delivery** version: master (83358fb62c0f711c70ad5a81030a6cae4017f103)

**berks** version: 5.2.0

**kitchen** version: 1.14.2

In Artifactory, I have this repository (virtual): **avirtual-repo**

**Berksfile contains**:

```
# cat Berksfile
# vim: ft=berksfile.ruby:

source "http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo"

cookbook "top_level_cookbook_name", ">= 0.0.0"
```

When, I'm running `berks install`, it ***sometimes*** succeeds (takes time to fetch cookbook and dependent cookbook versions that it finds during `berks install` process) and ***most of the times***, it fails with the following Timeout error messages.

For a **successful run** in Jenkins for `berks intsall`: I see this:

```
06:27:39 Resolving cookbook dependencies...
06:27:39 Fetching cookbook index from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo...
06:27:50 Installing active_directory (2.1.16) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
06:27:50 Installing dependent_project1 (3.0.19) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
...
......
....
bunch of more cookbooks are downloaded and it works
the end result is, I see a Berkshelf.lock file as expected in the workspace folder, containing locked versions for the top level cookbooks and its dependent cookbooks
.....
...
06:35:47 
06:35:47 -- Next steps - starts here onwards
```

For a **FAILED run** of `berks intstall` in Jenkins: I see the following errors:

**Error messages**:
*/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `gets': execution expired (* **Faraday::TimeoutError** *)*

*[2019-03-06T10:25:27.447804 #74360]* **ERROR -- : Actor crashed!**

*[2019-03-06T10:25:37.451708 #74360]* **ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!**

**Full Console output of Failed run**:

```
10:19:12 Resolving cookbook dependencies...
10:19:12 Fetching cookbook index from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo...
10:19:24 Installing active_directory (2.1.16) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:19:24 Installing apache_commons (0.3.8) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:19:24 Installing dependent_project1 (3.0.19) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:19:24 Installing automation_library (2.0.7) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:19:24 Installing chef_scripts (1.4.0) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:20:20 Installing dependent_project2 (4.10.20) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:20:21 Installing cots_database (7.1.0) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:20:21 Installing database (7.1.1) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:20:22 Installing db_devops (6.1.701) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:21:19 Installing dependent_project3 (3.3.20) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:21:19 Installing top_level_cookbook_name (0.1.6) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:21:20 Installing global_domains (0.1.1) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:21:20 Installing dependent_project4 (1.1.13) from http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo ([opscode] http://artifactory-server:8181/artifactory/api/chef/avirtual-repo/api/v1)
10:25:37 /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `gets': execution expired (Faraday::TimeoutError)
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `block in parse_header'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:801:in `parse_header'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:784:in `read_header'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:561:in `get_header'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1299:in `do_get_header'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1245:in `do_get_block'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1133:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:856:in `request'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/httpclient.rb:36:in `call'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/retry.rb:116:in `call'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ridley-5.1.0/lib/ridley/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:67:in `perform_with_redirection'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ridley-5.1.0/lib/ridley/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:60:in `call'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/community_rest.rb:116:in `find'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/community_rest.rb:100:in `download'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:61:in `try_download'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:35:in `block in download'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:34:in `each'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:34:in `download'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:105:in `install'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:63:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
10:25:37    from (celluloid):0:in `remote procedure call'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:92:in `value'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/proxies/sync_proxy.rb:33:in `method_missing'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/proxies/cell_proxy.rb:17:in `_send_'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/pool_manager.rb:41:in `_send_'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/pool_manager.rb:140:in `method_missing'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:63:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
10:25:37    from (celluloid):0:in `remote procedure call'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/future.rb:104:in `value'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/future.rb:68:in `value'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:175:in `map'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:175:in `install_from_universe'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:39:in `run'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/berksfile.rb:422:in `install'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:143:in `install'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:52:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:27:in `execute!'
10:25:37    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/bin/berks:5:in `<top (required)>'
10:25:37    from /usr/bin/berks:49:in `load'
10:25:37    from /usr/bin/berks:49:in `<main>'
10:25:37 E, [2019-03-06T10:25:27.447804 #74360] ERROR -- : Actor crashed!
10:25:37 Faraday::TimeoutError: execution expired
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `gets'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `block in parse_header'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:801:in `parse_header'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:784:in `read_header'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:561:in `get_header'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1299:in `do_get_header'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1245:in `do_get_block'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1133:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:856:in `request'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/httpclient.rb:36:in `call'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/retry.rb:116:in `call'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ridley-5.1.0/lib/ridley/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:67:in `perform_with_redirection'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ridley-5.1.0/lib/ridley/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:60:in `call'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/community_rest.rb:116:in `find'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/community_rest.rb:100:in `download'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:61:in `try_download'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:35:in `block in download'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:34:in `each'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/downloader.rb:34:in `download'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.2.0/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:105:in `install'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:63:in `dispatch'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
10:25:37    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
10:25:37 E, [2019-03-06T10:25:37.451708 #74360] ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!
10:25:37 
10:25:37 -- OK berks install failed, see console output above. Exiting Gracefully -- Berks Install Failed -- 
10:25:37
```

Looking at the source code of the gems .rb file, I see somewhere it talks about Timeout limit being **600** (seconds), but I think that's enough as during a successful run, everything works within 1-3 minutes. A failed run takes about 6-7 minutes before it finally times out by killing the whole single process thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple simple solution is to **restart** Artifactory service on the machine.

**OR**

Try this solution: To change the source file for the gem and bump the values. Save it, retry `berks install` to see. Restart Chef if required.

For ex:: Change values in the following file, line containing `options` and values i.e. **retry** to 3, **retry_interval** to 1 or 2, **open_timeout** to 60 and **timeout** to 60.

```
# ls -l /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-api-client-3.0.0/lib/berkshelf/api_client/connection.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2651 Dec 15  2016 /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-api-client-3.0.0/lib/berkshelf/api_client/connection.rb
[superuser@chefserver ~]
# grep timeout: $_

      options         = {retries: 3, retry_interval: 0.5, open_timeout: 30, timeout: 30}.merge(options)

[superuser@chefserver ~]
#
```

Here is related info: https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues/1287#issuecomment-60674084

Now, the important thing was **what could possibly cause these error** messages on the first place, when `berks install` is running (which fetch chef cookbook artifacts from a source repository (Artifactory) especially after `berks shelf uninstall` i.e. cleanup of Berks **SHELF** (cache area). It turned out that if you run a heave AQL (either using `curl -uU:pass ... -T aql.json` or `jfrog rt s ... --spec aql.json` (both json files have **different syntax** (jfrog cli --spec aql.json requires more outside `{`, `}` brackets) for same AQL search), then you'll notice, console output for that particular run (via CLI or some automation) will **NOT** return an output very quickly and in some cases, it'll take infinite time. If you have processes which runs such AQLs very often (ex: running from different runs of a / multiple Jenkins jobs) then `berks install` may get these errors intermittently.

Also, even if you `Control + ^C` (kill or any other way) kill that `curl`/`jfrog` command line run, it'll do **something** in Artifactory and possibly all future `berks install` runs will still get these timeout errors continuously until  **artifactory service restart** is performed as that will help resolve berks timeout issue (for now).

One should consider picking the following approaches (*specially picking the latter one than 1st*):

1. `berks shelf uninstall` + `berks install` (i.e. clean the shelf/cache and then, fetch dependent cookbooks versions - latest from a given source ex: Artifactory here AND update berk's CACHE)
2. `berks update` + `berks install` -- this will make any `berks` cmd faster (as you're not cleaning the whole cache and recreating it from scratch - as `berks install` after `berks shelf uninstall` takes time 1-10+ minutes depending upon a cookbook artifact's no. of other cookbook dependencies/tree/graph search).

See this post on **How to use Artifactory AQL** ***.json*** files using `curl` and `jfrog` cli: [JFrog CLI can't set properties on an artifact in JFrog Artifactory for the first property name and using SSH key examples for multi property search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916994/jfrog-cli-cant-set-properties-on-an-artifact-in-jfrog-artifactory-for-the-first)

See here how `berks update` works: [What exactly does "berks update <cookbook-name>" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034625/what-exactly-does-berks-update-cookbook-name-do) or

For more info on Berkshelf see here: https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html

One possible solution is to try creating (or modifying) `~/.berkshelf/config.json` and adding this to see if it helps?

```
{
  "api": {
    "timeout": 3000
  }
}
```